# How to insert/save Json into database

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I have the following class which parses the json and i'm trying to download the json into my database.My problem the value are not inserted into the database...How can I store the json into my database.

```
try{            
    JSONArray  location = json.getJSONArray("searchableLocations");         
    for(int
       i=0;i<location.length();i++){                        
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,
                        String>();  
        JSONObject e = location.getJSONObject(i);


        map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
        map.put("", "searchableLocations:" + e.getString("identifier"));
        map.put("name", "name: " +  e.getString("name"));
        //map.put("name", "priorityLevel: " +
               e.getString("priorityLevel"));
        map.put("", "numberOfPostcodes: " + 
           e.getString("numberOfPostcodes"));             
        mylist.add(map);            
    }       
        }catch(JSONException e)        {
     Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
       }
```

Here is where im try to insert the parse json into the database

```
databasePropertyManager = new DatabasePropertyManager(Database.this);   
databasePropertyManager.openDB();       
// Insert a the property list" 
databasePropertyManager.insertProperty("name", "identifer",
        "numberOfPostCodes");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing queries to create and insert data on DB,it's very simple by using ORMAN... refer the link below http://codeherenow.com/android/orman-saying-hello-part-2/...here everything based on Objects.

Comment: @ Senthil,can ORMAN accommodate the parsing of the json as well.

Comment: @Mohamed, it won't..you need to parse the JSON data and set it on ORMAN object..I need to point out that ORMAN handle the DB ease of use..